# apache-fop: unable to set width on a container

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i'm trying to generate a template for printing PDF-s. the inline container below should be fixed width, so the text doesn't overflow the elements on the right side. and i can't get it shrink.

i've tried with both block and inline containers, and various padding / margin options, but nothing worked. also width and max-width don't work.

```
        <xsl:if test="$vsadek/xy">
  ---->     <fo:inline-container width="40px" max-width="40px" padding-right="200pt">
                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$vsadek/xy"></xsl:value-of>
                    <xsl:if test="$vsadek/ab">
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vsadek/ab"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:inline-container>
        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: The FOP compliance page entry for `fo:inline-container` at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-object-inline-container states 'initial support: not all properties are implemented.' but the issue to which it refers does not state what is or is not implemented.

Comment: @TonyGraham i see... solutions i've found online say i need to wrap it in a container. either block or inline, and then set the width on that container. well i tried both and none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:
<fo:block-container height="42mm"  width="180mm" border-bottom-style="solid" border-width="thin">

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find a solution regarding width in the container, so i just opted to make a table and it worked.

here's the code:

```
<xsl:if test="$vsadek/ab">
    <fo:table>
---->   <fo:table-column column-width="950px"/>
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell>
                 <fo:block font-weight="bold" padding-bottom="0.3cm" keep-together.within-column="always">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$vsadek/ab"></xsl:value-of>
                    <xsl:if test="$vsadek/xy">
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vsadek/xy"></xsl:value-of>
                        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</xsl:if>
```